# How to install old PHP version

Tags: linux, php

I have installed php from apt -- How can I remove that version and install an older one?

Answer (score 12):

You can  install an older version of any package with Apt - you just have to look up the specific version name that you want. Assuming you're using Debian, you can look up old versions of packages at their site http://www.debian.org/distrib/packages

The format for installing said specific package is like this:

`apt-get install <package name>=<version>`

Such that if you want to install the version named 5.3.3-7+squeeze3, you use this:

`apt-get install php5=5.3.3-7+squeeze3`

But this also kind of brings me to the question "Why would you want to do that?" While you might have PHP scripts that require an older version of PHP, there hasn't been an upgrade in a *very* long time that has broken PHP scripts, in my experience (I run a web server that hosts a several hundred websites). As such, you'd be running a dangerously insecure version of PHP on your server. Are you *sure* you want to do that?

Comment: +1 for the word on security, but i disagree with the "Don't break anything" part.

Comment: I currently have a site hosted where the server runs 5.2. I would like to set up a virtual machine matching this so I can be sure when I develop that things work on the live server. However, I would like to upgrade if my host can do that (which I hope). But I am concerned about moving from 5.2 to 5.4.9. There must be breaking changes, no?

Comment: I work on a site which breaks in any php newer than 5.4. The cost is greater to update it to the newer php than to run an old version.

Comment: @Mnebuerquo that's what they all say, until they see the cost of security breach :)

Comment: Certainly running an older version is good for developing, especially if the production server is running an older version.

Comment: I know this is an old comment but this isn't helpful for todays time `E: Version '5.3.3-7+squeeze3' for 'php5' was not found`

Comment: Then you need to look up the version number of the package you want to install. Like I mentioned in the first sentence of my post.

Comment: @Ernie Sometimes you need older version of software XY for exploits & any testing purpose (compare how programm behaves under certain older software version). E.g. if i would like to learn how to exploit browsers, I'll need to install older browser versions and test exploit code. Same for php, etc...

Comment: Just now tried to install latest php5 available for Debian using `sudo apt-get install php5=5.6.40+dfsg-0+deb8u10` but I get `E: Version '5.6.40+dfsg-0+deb8u10' for 'php5' was not found`, although it is listed: https://packages.debian.org/jessie/php5

Answer (score 5):

```
apt-get remove --purge yourphppackage
```

Go here : http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php5/

Get the deb file of the version you need.

```
dpkg -i yourphppackage.deb
```

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall the old version using `sudo apt-get purge php` then Using this https://www.php.net/releases/ link we can able to download any tar compression of the specific version of PHP.

Follow the below steps

1. Extract the tar file
2. `cd php-7.0.*`
3. `./configure`
4. `make`
5. `sudo make install`
6. Check php version using `php -v`

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to do `apt install libsqlite3-dev` for `./configure`